# 2D Arraylist- Predict output for the code

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

(link: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/array_2d/) 
having difficulty in performing a dry run for the following code with performOps being called with

A : [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] .

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> performOps(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A) {
       ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            B.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

            for (int j = 0; j < A.get(i).size(); j++) {
                B.get(i).add(0);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < A.get(i).size(); j++) {
                B.get(i).set(A.get(i).size() - 1 - j, A.get(i).get(j));
            }
        }
        return B;
}
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding it?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The output will be

```
4 3 2 1 
8 7 6 5 
12 11 10 9
```

You must be trying to initialize A.That is not the case here.The value of A is

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12
```

and then the output of the further code is asked in the question.Please read the question carefully.Reach out if you need anything else.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting the variable values for one or two loops. That will be easier to understand such questions and if possible code it in editor and debug through the code one step at a time.

I have tried for one loop.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> performOps(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        //A.size() is 3
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            B.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

            //First Loop i = 0; A.get(0).size() = 4; Four elements in first index of array list
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                B.get(0).add(0); //Setting all elements to zeros
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                B.get(0).set(4 - 1 - j, A.get(0).get(j));
                //For j = 0
                // B.get(0).set(3, 1); //A.get(0).get(0) = 1

                //For j = 1
                B.get(0).set(2, 2); //A.get(0).get(1) = 2

                //For j = 2
                B.get(0).set(1, 3); // A.get(0).get(2) = 3


                //For j = 3
                B.get(0).set(0, 4); //A.get(0).get(3) = 4
            }

            //At the end of above loop B=[[4, 3, 2 ,1]]
        }
        return B;
}
```

By the way the output will be two dimensional collection with each inner collection elements in reverse order.